# how i clip this image from top bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this image description the error:

[image]

this is code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.4,
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/backZak.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 2.5,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          assetName[1],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Clip.hardEdge ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.